# Is there any library which can be used to convert CSS into its equivalent XML styles which can be used in Word Document?

Tags: javascript, css, xml-parsing, openxml

I need to convert an HTML to DOCX. I have Pandoc as well as Blob to convert html to
docx. But none of them preserves the styles, if i can create an xml style file for word document then it will be done.

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow